# Static IP for external device TCP connection at the same time than having automatic DHCP for internet connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp, ip, alias

I'm kind of a novice for Ubuntu and trying to find a working solution for my problem. I have an external device with fixed IP 192.168.1.x connected through a switch and I need to have a TCP connection to this device. I am able to set up a static IP 192.168.1.x in the same subnet and successfully connect the device but then I cannot connect to internet.

At the moment my solution is to change with two connections but I would like to have this so that I can connect the device and web without changing the connection all the time while I am debugging the device and creating software.

I have tried to make an alias with a static IP for my network card but that results only to a solution in which I am able perhaps able to connect to web but not the device or not to connect anything. I changed the `/etc/network/interfaces` as follows:

> auto enp0s31f6:0
>   iface enp0s31f6:0 inet static
>   name Ethernet alias LAN card
>   address 192.168.1.20
>   netmask 255.255.255.0
>   broadcast 192.168.1.255
>   network 192.168.1.0`

Then I get the following result with `ifconfig` after restarting the network:

> enp0s31f6:0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:81:d7:62:1f:d5
>
> > ```
> >      inet addr:192.168.1.20  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
> >      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
> >      Interrupt:16 Memory:dd500000-dd520000
> > ```

And `route` command gives:

[image: route command output]

I don't know if the problem is in the gateway or if the solution just doesn't work, with route, I also tried adding the gateway with:

`sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1 enp0s31f6:0`

but that makes the internet connection not to work.

Then In addition I thought maybe bridging could do this, but I followed the instructions here https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html and couldn't get that working.

In addition I tried to add the route to my network connection but couldn't get that working either. I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me with this problem. I have been searching a solution for 2 days and I doubt that an easy solution exists.

Comment: What is your internet gateways IP? The 10.x.x.x? Have you tried to ping outside or just tried to open a webpage?

Comment: `route add default gw 192.168.1.1 enp0s31f6` not sure what your :0 should accomplish?

Comment: I tried to ping outside and I'm able to do that as well open the pages when it works but I am not able to ping on the device unless I change a static ip address. And when I change a static ip, I cannot ping to the gateway 10.x.x.x.

I thought that if the gateway of the alias for the network should be within the ip starting 192.168.1.x which I want to connect so that I would be able to connect that if I change the gateway. But really I don't know if it makes any sense, I am just guessing.

Comment: Do you know how networks work in general, or did you just configure everything on a hunch on how it should be?

Comment: Well I have some basic understanding but yes Im a a real novice for this stuff.

Comment: You have to use the same network to communicate with both. You can not use 192.168.x.x/24 and at the same time communicate with a 10.x.x.x/x network. You either have to use the 10.x.x.x network on the other client aswell or connect those via a router and add the router to your route as the next hop of the network 192.168. that you want to reach. Or connect them point to point/switch via an extra ethernet adapter and use that connection to communicate with that  one client and use the other interface as your internet ethernet port.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by making alias for my ethernet. It was just that I needed to add the original interface into `/etc/network/interface` followingly:

> auto enp0s31f6
>   iface enp0s31f6 inet dhcp
>
> auto enp0s31f6:0
>   iface enp0s31f6:0 inet static
>           name Ethernet alias LAN card
>           address 192.168.1.20
>           netmask 255.255.255.0
>           broadcast 192.168.1.255
>           network 192.168.1.0

My problem was that since originally my ethernet was not defined in the `etc/network/interfaces` and I didn't define it, the system lost it's connection to the network.